# Unable to install dlib module

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning

While installing dlib module, all the subprocesses are killed and showing that legacy error.
The same error is faced when face-recognition is installed.

I tried to do this with github repositry files.But also it is not working for both of the module.
I want to know how to install successfully both the modules in python 3.11.1 version on windows 10 laptop

Comment: add the full error trace, not a picture.

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-dlib-library-for-python-in-windows-10/ :

Install Cmake from https://cmake.org/download/ (Add to PATH)

Install the c++ compiler of the visual studio code community version. For that go to the visual studio code official website https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

Then pip install cmake and dlib